# Convert an UIImage in a texture

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, textures

In my opengl project I need to convert an UIImage in texture; what's the way to do it?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't test the following but i will decompose the conversion in 3 steps:

1. Extract info for your image:

   ```
   UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageToApplyAsATexture.png"];
   CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
   int width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
   int height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
   ```
2. Allocate a `textureData` with the above properties:

   ```
   GLubyte* textureData = (GLubyte *)malloc(width * height * 4); // if 4 components per pixel (RGBA)

   CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
   NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
   NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;  
   CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(textureData, width, height,
                                                bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

   CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

   CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
   CGContextRelease(context);
   ```
3. Set-up your texture:

   ```
   GLuint textureID;    
   glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
   glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);
   ```

**EDIT:**

Read [this tut](http://blog.csdn.net/opengl_es/article/details/25240061); everything is explained from the conversion of one image to a texture and applying a texture in an iOS environment.

Comment: I have two question: my image is 1024x768 where I should set these valiues? and finally what's my texture?

Comment: if you know your images dimensions you don't need to extract the width and height just set it directly

Comment: your 2d texture corresponds to the gl object you are creating when invoking glTexImage2D, you can access it through it name: textureID

Comment: why context is a variable that is unused? and you can tell me how to set this texture ad backgroung in glpaint?

Comment: mmmm I'n not expert of openGL can you help me and tell how to set this texture in glPaint texture?

Comment: did u check the link for the tut?

Comment: texture tutorial link is broken, any info on finding a mirror?

Comment: I believe you can use this one now: http://blog.csdn.net/opengl_es/article/details/25240061

Comment: is there any way to do this in swift3? do you have any links?

Comment: @tiguero textureID always zero can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is swift version of getting texture out of an UIImage

```
func setupTexture(sourceImage: UIImage) -> GLuint {

guard let textureImage = sourceImage.cgImage else {
    print("Failed to load image")
    return 0
}

let width = textureImage.width
let height = textureImage.height

/*
 it will write one byte each for red, green, blue, and alpha – so 4 bytes in total.
 */

let textureData = calloc(width * height * 4, MemoryLayout<GLubyte>.size) //4 components per pixel (RGBA)
let spriteContext = CGContext(data: textureData,
                              width: width,
                              height: height,
                              bitsPerComponent: 8,
                              bytesPerRow: width * 4,
                              space: textureImage.colorSpace!,
                              bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)

spriteContext?.draw(textureImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

var textName = GLuint()
glGenTextures(1, &textName)
glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), textName)
glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_NEAREST)
glTexImage2D(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), 0, GL_RGBA, GLsizei(width),
             GLsizei(height), 0, GLenum(GL_RGBA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), textureData)

return textName
```

}

**Note: Need to keep in mind that Core Graphics flips images when we load them in.**

Comment: textName always zero why ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this using the GLKit framework:

```
//Path to image
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"textureImage" ofType:@"png"];

//Set eaglContext
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:[[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2]];

//Create texture
NSError *theError;    
GLKTextureInfo *texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:nil error:&theError];
glBindTexture(texture.target, texture.name);
```

`texture.name` is The OpenGL context’s name for the texture.