# rendering some characters in OpenGL ES 2.x scene

Tags: ios, opengl-es, character

I’m new for OpenGL ES 2.x on iOS, and I’m trying to render some characters in the OpenGL ES 2.x scene. But I don’t know how to do it.

So anyone who can point me in the direction of an Objective-C tutorial or post some sample code?

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is asked a lot because OpenGL does not have built-in support for text fonts.  There is a good survey of solutions and discussion here:

```
http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/fontsurvey/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557535/text-font-rendering-in-opengles-2-ios-coretext-options-and-best-practice
```

But the easiest solution by far is to use the Print3D class in the PowerVR SDK:

```
http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp
```